# Difficulties reaching a child state with Ionic / UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have the following **parent** states:

```
  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
  .state('tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html",
    controller: "TabCtrl"
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:
  .state('tab.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
        resolve: {authResolve: authResolve}
  }
}
```

})

```
// 
.state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl',
        resolve: {authResolve: authResolve}
      }
    }
  })
```

and the following **child** state of `tab.dash`

```
  .state('tab.album', {
    url: '/dash/:albumName',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-album.html',
        controller: 'AlbumCtrl',
        resolve: {authResolve: authResolve}
      }
    }
  })
```

In addition I have one **independent** state

```
// none tabs/nonview pages
  .state('neutral', {
    url: '/neutral',
    templateUrl: 'templates/single-neutral.html',
    controller: 'NeutralCtrl',
    resolve: {authResolve: authResolve}
  })
```

---

THE PROBLEM

In the independent state `neutral`, when I try to redirect to the child state `tab.album` then it only works if first I reached the `neutral` state from `tab.album`. When I reach `neutral` from `tab.home` and then try to redirect to `tab.album`, then I get redirected to `tab.dash`, the parent of `tab.album`. So to make it more clear:

This works:

```
tab.home > tab.dash > tab.album > neutral > tab.album
```

This does **not** work:

```
tab.home > neutral > tab.album
```

What is the reason for this and how can I solve it?

Comment: tab.album is child of tab, not tab.dash

Comment: @johnandrews I have the same problem. If you fixed it, could you please edit and upload your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a blog post that shows how to force the tab to go to the top level whenever it is activated. http://www.clearlyinnovative.com/ionic-framework-tabs-go-home-view/

- the codepen: http://codepen.io/aaronksaunders/pen/rlvFq

You should be able to use the same approach to tell the tab to goto a particular child state based on a `stateParameter` you pass to it.